# Smart captcha for ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, captcha

I want to make a secure ajax requests using captcha for no spam

my problem is when the page have 2 request like this :

Button 1 - Button 2

The captcha code changes if I click on Button 1 or Button 1

this codes maybe can understand my problem

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<script>
var code_captcha = 1234; // generated by php
</script>
<inpt type="button" value="Request 1" onclick="ajax_request('send_message.php', captcha = code_captcha);" />
<inpt type="button" value="Request 2" onclick="ajax_request('add_comment.php', captcha = code_captcha);" />
```

**send_message.php / add_comment ....**

```
<?
session_start();
$code = $_SESSION["code"];
if ($code == $_POST[code_captcha]){
    echo 'status:ok';
    $_SESSION["code"] = "";
}else{
    echo 'status:error';
}
?>
```

the line clear the captcha code **$_SESSION["code"] = "";**.

so if I click for the first time on a request 100% I return a **ok status**

but if I click for the second time on a request 100% I return a **error** because the session cleared

any ideas and thanks in advance

**If you are a vBulletin coder I think you seen token in header for no spam comment, messages etc**

Comment: Don't clear the session variable?

Comment: why are you keeping the captcha code in plain text? that's the worst practice I've ever seen.

Comment: because if the user loggedin and want to comment on post he deosn't  want to every time paste the captcha code

Answer (score -1):

I know this doesn't solve your

"I want to make a secure ajax requests using captcha for no spam" problem

But, I want to solve your no spam problem. From a usability standpoint captchas suck terrible for the users. The one on here rejects me at least 3 times because apparently, I'm not human. Be unique and creative. Get/Create your own table of strings that ask the user a question that computers can't figure out, and then create there answers.

I know. I know. It sounds like more work, but think of your users.

Comment: Ah! Point proven. Captcha gets me again! :(

Comment: no no it's make the user bored, every time when he want to post comment ask the question hhhhhh, it's stupid idea

Comment: IF stupid idea means a bunch of usability testing that agrees with me... Ya, it's a stupid idea. :)

Comment: Anyways, I don't mean to make you waste your time on my idea. I was just trying to provide an outside the box solution.

Comment: Thanks Sure, if you have more ideas give me give me :)